# Ошибка компиляции cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Я пытаюсь запустить в clion чужой проект с использованием cmake и Qt. Долго ковырялся и устанавливал недостающие библиотеки. В итоге пришел к ошибке cmake, которую не нашел как поправить.

Ссылка на проект: github.com/Constantor/fractals3d

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.2.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER=FALSE -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" C:\Users\degwr\CLionProjects\fractals3d
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30133.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
-- Found WrapAtomic: TRUE  
-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing: Vulkan_LIBRARY Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing: Vulkan_LIBRARY Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/degwr/CLionProjects/fractals3d/cmake-build-debug-visual-studio

Cannot get compiler information:
    Compiler exited with error code 2: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe" @C:\Users\degwr\AppData\Local\Temp\response-file3070191229199956645 C:\Users\degwr\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-file12988370343547114978 | @response-file3070191229199956645=/TP -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGLWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -MD -Wall -Wextra -O3 -ffast-math -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -utf-8 -std:c++17 /Be /Bd /EP
    ЋЇвЁ¬Ё§ЁагойЁ© Є®¬ЇЁ«пв®а Microsoft (R) C/C++ ўҐабЁЁ 19.29.30133 ¤«п x64
    (C) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation).  ‚бҐ Їа ў  § йЁйҐ­л.
    
    all:
        @cd C:\Users\degwr\CLionProjects\fractals3d\cmake-build-debug-visual-studio
        @set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt
        @set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64
        @set CL=
        @set _CL_=
        @set LINK=
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe @<< C:\Users\degwr\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-file12988370343547114978
    /TP -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGLWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -MD -Wall -Wextra -O3 -ffast-math -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -utf-8 -std:c++17 /Be /Bd /EP<<
    
    cl /TP -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGLWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -MD -Wall -Wextra -O3 -ffast-math -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -utf-8 -std:c++17 /Be /Bd /EP
    cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  error D8021: ­Ґ¤®ЇгбвЁ¬л© зЁб«®ў®©  аЈг¬Ґ­в "/Wextra"
    
    

[Failed to reload]
```

[image: Настройки CMake]

Comment: Вы уверены насчет `-G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles"`?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я лично ничего не настраивал и не указывал параметров запуска. Скопировал проект с Github и пытался его запустить. Поэтому я не знаю в каком месте исправлять то, что вы указали. Насколько я понимаю, что, что вы цитируете задано в cmake изначально

Comment: ¿А почему вы вообще решили, что этот проект можно собрать на windows в clion используя компилятор vc++?

Comment: Проект мультиплатформенный как я понял, а как запустить то же самое на линуксе, я представляю еще хуже.

Comment: Хоть бы ссылку на проект дали...

Comment: https://github.com/Constantor/fractals3d

Comment: ну там малой кровью не обойдёшься - там ещё и Qt нужен.

Comment: qt установил, не с первого раза его показал проекту конечно, но это я переборол